Do religious people actually believe all that stuff, or is it some kind of adult make-believe?
[Letter of Thomas Jefferson to James Smith][1], 1822:

"We find in the writings of His biographers [the Gospels] a groundwork of vulgar ignorance, of things impossible, of superstitions, fanaticisms and fabrications."


"The day will come when the mystical generation of Jesus, by the supreme being as his father in the womb of a virgin, will be classed with the fable of the generation of Minerva in the brain of Jupiter."


"Man, once surrendering his reason, has no remaining guard against absurdities the most monstrous, and like a ship without rudder is the sport of every wind. With such persons, gullibility, which they call "faith," takes the helm from the hand of reason, and the mind becomes a shipwreck."

And that was just from one letter.
Do intelligent people believe in miracle claims central to religious dogmas? Do they actually know that it's nonsense, or they really believe it? Do they explain it away? Ignore it completely? Get angry when it's pointed out?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Is this question about religion as such or about the Christian religion(s)? If youv see the chat below Ted Wrigley's answer you'll see why clarifying this matters

Scuttle? Re. Votes: On this question, I'm in the reopen queue not the VTC queue.  I add »in Christendom« to underscore that questions like this one have very little meaning not just outside Christendom but even outside WASP America

I think three main concepts work here - cognitive dissonance, doublethink and compartmentalization. And also perks for socialization, being part of a community.
So to put it briefly - religious belief requires a kind of cognitive dissonance. Man, once surrendering his reason, has no remaining guard against absurdities. This is where doublethink comes into play - folks can compartmentalize their beliefs, accepting miraculous claims while engaging in rational thought in other parts of their lives.
People are also drawn to the community that faith offers—the rituals, the social even absurd ones. When confronted with the contradictions of their faith, many react with anger or defensiveness, as you mentioned. This reaction is not just to the challenge itself, but to the threat against their community and the perks it provides.
From my experience working with many churches for most people there it's a doublethink. They don't rly believe but they believe that they believe. It's like a deep role-play.

Mathematicians "compartmentalise" their beliefs by applying a different standard for determining truth in mathematics (i.e. strict logical proof) than they do in everyday life (i.e. the evidence of their senses). They engage in completely different kinds of thought in order to determine their beliefs about mathematics vs. their beliefs about the natural world, and don't apply the latter kind of thought to decide the former. Do mathematicians have cognitive dissonance, and is doing mathematics a kind of doublethink? If not, why not?

Only one comment: I do not think that "man is naturally rational" and thus religious beliefs are "cognitive errors". Most religious belief, like many other beliefs, are not "rationally chosen" but culturally and socially "imposed": they are more "behavious" than "ideas".

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA absolutely agree

There's an interesting recent conversation between Ayaan Hirsi Ali and Richard Dawkins. Ali was a staunch atheist who's recently turned Christian. A bewildered Dawkins asks Do you really believe all this virgin birth etc stuff? Ali answers: I choose to believe Note how cognition changes to volition as irreligious flips to religious

@MissUnderstands The point is not that mathematicians are "in a different mental state" when doing mathematics, it's that mathematical beliefs exist in a separate ontology (i.e. a separate universe of facts) and are acquired using a separate epistemology (i.e. a separate way of deciding which things are facts, and of finding new facts), which they use only for mathematics. This answer points out that religious people do that for their religious beliefs and says it is "doublethink".

As for "you people", thanks for the prejudice against religious people, but I'm not religious, not that that matters.

@kaya3 next level of political correctness for you - when a psychiatrist says somebody needs help cause he is mentally ill, he is "prejudiced against people with alternative perception". Go ahead, use it. :) I am stating the facts, if they hurt your feelings, it doesn't mean I am prejudiced. Religion is a tool of control, religious people are brainwashed to be controlled. That's how it works.

@Groovy That doesn't answer my question. If it is "doublethink" to use different philosophical tools to analyse different kinds of propositions, then mathematicians engage in exactly that kind of doublethink, too. Perhaps you could respond to that rather than making wild guesses about my feelings?

No worldviews cohere.  The Munchausen Trilemma insures that.  So yes, all religious who think their worldview is coherent are engaged in a form of "doublethink".  So are all materialists, physicalists, and ontological naturalists.  Your innuendo that miracles (I.E. belief in either interactive spiritual dualism, or idealism) have been refuted beyond question for any "rational" person is -- actually an undemonstrated "faith" view, and false.


Do intelligent people believe in miracle claims central to religious dogmas?

There are individuals who seem to be both intelligent and believers in miracles. I'll provide a few examples:

(Christianity) Craig Keener: book1, book2, video1 (debate), video2 (debate).
(Christianity) Gary Habermas: book1, book2, video.
(Christianity) J. P. Moreland: book, video
(Parapsychology) Dean Radin: book1, book2, book3, video
(Hinduism) What are the most documented miracles in Hinduism?


Do they actually know that it's nonsense, or they really believe it? Do they explain it away? Ignore it completely? Get angry when it's pointed out?

These individuals appear to be fully convinced that miracles are real. Do they secretly know it’s all nonsense and are merely pretending to believe? I think that’s a loaded question, one that implicitly assumes miracles don't exist—an assumption that could be seen as question-begging from the perspective of those who support the reality of miracles. In contentious debates like this, it’s more useful and intellectually responsible to recognize that belief exists on a spectrum, as Richard Dawkins outlines in his spectrum of theistic probability.

So we need to start testing those miracles, if the question turns on that. Or, stop considering the issue as being related to science. Either go in the tent, or go away from it.

@ScottRowe - perfect! If you have faith, believe. If not, stop searching purported proofs: 2 millenia of Western (at least) discussions found NONE.

@MissUnderstands: generally, if you want to know what people think, it's more effective to ask them rather than asking someone else what they theoretically might think. If you ask here, all we are going to be able to do is point to what has been written or recorded, mention that there is no general answer, and tell you to research it deeper if you don't find that satisfying.

Also, if you want to know what people think, it's more effective to ask them without insulting them. Your question is effectively, "given that what religious people claim they believe is false, they must be either stupid or lying - which one is it?" No wonder you aren't getting answers from many believers. Though to be clear, if your intention really is to get answers from individual believers about just their own beliefs, then it's really more of a survey than a question, and I don't think Philosophy SE is the right place.

@keshlam  if you want to know what people think, it's more effective to ask them === One would think so. Yet, I innocently (yes really) asked "Do you actually believe this, given that someone we both revere says it's "vulgar ignorance, things impossible"? === You (plural) answered it, and one Christian here induced me to change my position on intelligent design (slightly). === The Christianity stax 1) pasted a wall of enchanted spells 2) declared they shall always Stand Fierce on the Side of the Lord no matter what "science" says, and 3) Banned me. === Like, what does that contrast tell you?

As is well known from news reports, freedom fighters in the Middle East are willing to give their lives so as to go to heaven as promised by their religious leaders.  The inescapable conclusion seems to be that "they really believe all that stuff".

Now that's a damn good answer and I'm marking it as the accepted one! === Although I did read a few years ago that the Islam fighters in the Middle East are almost all illiterate teens-20s  with no female relationship. I was actually interested in cognitive dissonance in intelligent people. But you make an excellent point that I overlooked — that people are willing to blow themselves up over it is proof positive that they actually believe the s***.

This is not a very strong argument. People have knowingly given up their lives fighting for many causes throughout history, especially those relating to the continued existence of their own people, their way of life, or other existential or political causes. Emily Davison walked in front of King George V's horse to protest for women's suffrage. Terrorists may believe they will go to heaven if they die for their cause, but they still have a cause, and they might very well choose to die fighting whether or not they believe they will go to heaven.

A better example would be cult members who participate in group suicide. Cults like Heaven's Gate generally don't have political goals in the real world, so their member's actions can only be attributed to their supernatural beliefs. Still, whether you take terrorists or cult members, this doesn't really answer the question "do religious people ..." because neither of those groups really represent religious people. If the question is instead "has a religious person ever ..." then such examples might be sufficient to answer.

That's a a very weak argument, cause the number of suicide fanatics is almost irrelevant to the total number of Muslims. You just hear about them in media a lot. And the question was about general population.

@kaya3, Presumably  Emily Davison walked in front of King George V's horse to protest for women's suffrage because she believed in the cause of women's suffrage.  So your claim seems to be a non-sequitur.

@MikhailKatz That is entirely the point. Emily Davison was also a devout Christian who presumably believed she would go to heaven, but from her actions we cannot infer that she really believed that, because her willingness to die can be readily explained by her support for women's suffrage. Likewise, terrorists' willingness to die for their causes can be readily explained by their support for those causes. It is a mistake to infer that that willingness to die can only be explained by a religious belief, yet this answer calls such reasoning "inescapable".

I still think your argument is weak.  The idea that the freedom fighters are willing to sacrifice their lives because of the promise of heaven is a widely discussed idea and seems to be generally acknowledged.  Your parallel with the situation with Davison and King George is dubious.

I haven't really made my own argument, rather I've criticised your argument by showing that it doesn't apply in an analogous case. It may well be that the other case isn't analogous to the argument you wanted to make, because of evidence which applies to one case and not the other. But the evidence which breaks the analogy is missing from in your argument. To establish your argument, you need to show that Islamic-extremist terrorists would not be willing to die for their causes except for their belief in the afterlife (or, show something along those lines).

@kaya3, People have certainly been willing to risk their lives for various causes, but the phenomenon we find today in the Middle East is somewhat different.  When a Sunni blows himself up to take a bunch of Shiites with him, he is not merely risking his life but giving it up with 100% certainly.  Bernard Lewis has written about this new phenomenon, and has linked it to heavenly promise.

It's true that Emily Davison might not have intended to die as a result of her protest. But there are other political protestors who have knowingly died for their causes, notably people who commit self-immolation. Many such protestors are religious, but nonetheless have strong political motivations for their actions. I don't think you can universally say that people who knowingly and certainly die for their causes must have a sincere belief in a heavenly promise.

@kaya3, you may want to read up on your Bernard Lewis.

Rather, if Bernard Lewis has written something which makes your argument stronger, you may want to quote it in your answer.

Criticism like Jefferson’s criticism is as old as the Christian religion. And one finds the criticism of superstition and miracles similarly concerning other religions, sometimes less, sometimes more.
You ask:

How can intelligent people believe such things?

My answer:

Much explanation is due to the fact that they are brought up under
the influence of the religion in question, already at  an age where
they could not question what they learned.
A second cause: Superstition allows one to believe what one wants to
believe, and to arrange the world according to one’s own needs and
wishes.


No one should be taught anything religious until after they are 25 and capable of evaluating it.

@ScottRowe Would that include Santa Claus stories?

Let's be clear: we do not understand (and may never understand) the vast majority of the universe. We are like that archetypal person standing under a streetlight (or by a campfire), holding what little we can see and know with certainty, and worrying about what lies in the shadows beyond our meager capacity for sight. It's an unfortunate situation…

Some of us choose to limit ourselves to what we can see and know
Some of us decide to speculate about what lies in the dark
Some few of us face the ambiguity, and cope with the angst

Whatever it takes, it's all good
People who embrace religion take it as an article of faith. It isn't that they know it's nonsense, or believe it wholeheartedly, or explain it away, or ignore it outright. It's that they choose to accept it, because not accepting it makes the world an ugly, mean, base, stupid place in their view. Nobody wants to live in that kind of world. And yes, some people get angry when confronted, because confrontation (in their minds) is only a tool to make the world stupid and ugly. Who wants that?
I respect Jefferson, but Jefferson was a firebrand for reason, and like all firebrands he tends more towards heat than light. Faith takes over where ignorance and reason both fail, and we should appreciate its value (at very least) as a stop-gap.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Do intelligent people believe in miracle claims central to religious dogmas?

There is no telling. If you believe in God, you might as well believe in His miracles. You have to ask yourself, though, if you think that that is the hallmark of an intelligent person.

Do they actually know that it's nonsense, or they really believe it?

Some people have been known to lie.

Do they explain it away? Ignore it completely? Get angry when it's pointed out?

Not sure what you mean. If they don't lie and believe in miracles then there is nothing to ignore or to explain away. If they do lie and don't believe in miracles then there is nothing to ignore or to explain away.

I'm glad we got that cleared up! It just leaves the 'anger' part.

@ScottRowe I know. It is mere folk psyhology. Nothing to do with philosopy.

I seem to remember that it was one of the popes who said "Those who believe religion and science are opposed either make science say that which it never said, or religion teach that which it never taught."
Unfortunately, given some flavors of American fundamentalism, I think he's overoptimistic on the latter. (I have my own theories about how that situation evolved, but I have no idea whether a historian would agree with me.)


I seem to remember that it was one of the popes who said "Those who believe religion and science are opposed either make science say that which it never said, or religion teach that which it never taught." == A WISE pope!


There are wise people in religion, who accept that science is about how the world works and religion is about what lessons can be drawn from the world (ideally updating those as our knowledge increases). In fact, I have known people who simultaneously follow multiple religions because they find parts of each useful metaphors. The question of whether they "believe all that" is a finely shaded one, not a binary yes/no, even for a single person; when "they"  becomes collective the question becomes unanswerable

Your belief that the miracle claims of religions are "nonsense" cannot be well supported in any justification I have ever seen.
There is not any logic based objection to interactive dualism.
The empirical case for material causal closure is -- falsified by the causal role of abstract objects, and of our consciousness, by the falsification of materialism by Einstein, and by Hempel' Dilemma preventing physics from serving as a stand in for hopeful former materialists.
Insults and name-calling toward interactive dualists, rather than evidential and reasoned arguments, have become the far more common method of "arguing" for materialism over the last several decades, as in this question.
Writing as an interactive dualist -- yes I believe that the spirit realm interacts with the physical, producing what physicalists consider miracles.

@MissUnderstands  You appear not to understand that Einstein demonstrating that matter is not a fundamental essence of our universe is a refutation of materialism.  Per Wikipedia: "Materialism is a form of philosophical monism which holds that matter is the fundamental substance in nature".

Ohhh boy. I'm probably not the one you want to present that argument to.

It just seems like there are two different realms of study, and no point whatsoever in trying to connect them.
